# Kotlin Fuel.download creates an empty file

Tags: http, kotlin, kotlin-fuel

Kotlin code:

```
Fuel.download("http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_mgsasc.zip")
        .destination { response, url -> File("mega.zip").apply { println(absolutePath) } }
        .responseString()
```

This **particular URL** returns *length: -1* and creates an empty file. How can I fix it?

Response:

```
(--> http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_mgsasc.zip
"Body : (empty)"
"Headers : (1)"
Accept-Encoding : compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0
, <-- 200 (http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_mgsasc.zip)
Response : OK
Length : -1
Body : ((empty))
Headers : (10)
Transfer-Encoding : [chunked]
Accept-Ranges : [bytes]
Server : [Microsoft-IIS/6.0]
ETag : ["39fa791f4d64d41:d118"]
Last-Modified : [Mon, 15 Oct 2018 06:05:50 GMT]
Age : [33]
Date : [Mon, 15 Oct 2018 13:36:58 GMT]
Via : [AX-CACHE-2.7:210]
X-Powered-By : [ASP.NET]
Content-Type : [application/x-zip-compressed]
, [Success: ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The server does not send a "Content-length" header at all for URL http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_mgsasc.zip

The "Length : -1" that you're seeing probably comes from the Fuel library.

The response uses "Transfer-encoding:" of "chunked", which is a special transfer encoding that doesn't require a content-length up front.

It doesn't look like Fuel supports the "chunked" transfer encoding. I've searched their github repo for both "transfer-encoding" and "chunked" and doesn't return any hits for either.

You may want to suggest a new feature in the library.